# MongoDb return records only if $lookup cond is occur

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a class model which has field ref.

I'm trying to fetch only records that match the condition in lookup.

so what i did:

```
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'fields',
        localField: "field",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: 'FieldCollege',
      },
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        "FieldCollege": {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            {
              $filter: {
                input: "$FieldCollege",
                as: "field",
                cond: {
                  $eq: ["$$field.level", req.query.level]
                }
              }
            }, 0
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

The above code works fine and returning the `FieldCollege` if the cond is matched.

but the thing is, i wanted to return the class records only if the `FieldCollege` is not empty.

I'm totally new to mongodb. so i tried something like this:

```
    {
      $match: {
        'FieldCollege': { $exists: true, $ne: [] }

      }
    },
```

Obv this didn't work.

does mongodb support something like this or am i complicating things?

**EDIT**:

the result from the above code:

```
    "Classes": [
      {
          "_id": "613245664c6ea614e001fcef",
          "name": "test",
          "language": "en",
          "year_cost": "3232323",
          "FieldCollege":[] // with $unwind
      }
  ],
```

expected Result:

```
   "Classes": [
     // FieldCollege is empty 
  ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the good option is to use lookup with pipeline, and see the final version of your query,

- `$lookup` with fields collection and match your both conditions
- `$limit` to result one document
- `$match` `FieldCollege` is not empty []
- `$addElemAt` to get first element from result `FieldCollege`

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "fields",
      let: { field: "$field" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              { $expr: { $eq: ["$$field", "$_id"] } },
              { level: req.query.level }
            ]
          }
        },
        { $limit: 1 }
      ],
      as: "FieldCollege"
    }
  },
  { $match: { FieldCollege: { $ne: [] } } },
  {
    $addFields: {
      FieldCollege: { $arrayElemAt: ["$FieldCollege", 0] }
    }
  }
]
```